# Import Data from BigQuery to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, google-bigquery

I need to extract data from Google BigQuery to SQL Server. The dataset for extraction has many columns and rows. Is there any big query connector available in SSIS?

Answer (score 2):

You also can use python package [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

[To read from BQ](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_gbq.html):

```
pandas.DataFrame.read_gbq(query, project_id=None, index_col=None, col_order=None, reauth=False, verbose=None, private_key=None, dialect='legacy', **kwargs)
```

[Send to SQL](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

```
pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(name, con, schema=None, if_exists='fail', index=True, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)
```

Another way is to use [Simba ODBC Driver for BiqQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/partners/simba-drivers/)

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, there is no built-in solution that Microsoft provides to extract Google BigQuery to SQL Server via SSIS. But there are a bunch of third-party extensions/tools that provide this service. I haven't used any, so I can't make a recommendation, but a quick Google search will provide a bunch of extensions/tools that you can use:

[Connect google bigquery to SQL Server with SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6056421f-c868-4d7b-9dd1-a40dc4216eaa/connect-google-bigquery-to-sql-server-with-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

A common one that I do see in many Microsoft Blog forum posts is CDATA:
[SSIS Data Flow Source & Destination for Google BigQuery](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CDATASOFTWARE.SSISDataFlowSourceDestinationforGoogleBigQuery)

It's Visual Studio extension that connects SQL Server with live Google BigQuery data through SSIS Workflows. F.Y.I. the marketplace link is for a trial version of the extension.